# JSON loop through data and print into div

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am grabbing some data via URL from an external site (Cross Origin..) and I want to display the results (for each) into their own html div's.

How do I go about this, what is the simplest effective method?

**Here is the current code**

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'https://*****************/DirectDownload/GetShopProducts?token=*********&searchString=polo',
    success: function(products){
        var html = '<div>';
          $.each(products, function (index, value) {
              html += '<h2>Item Code:</h2><p>' + value.ItemCode + '</p>';
          });
          html += '</div>';
          $('#output').html(html);
  }
  });
  </script>
```

**The results in console log**

```
[

{
"ItemCode":"1100-M-NV-FER03EM2-FER",
"Description":"Osprey Deluxe Poloshirt",
"TechnicalInfo":"",
"ImageName":"1100NAR.jpg",
"FfProductCode":"1100-M-NV-EM2-FER",
"CategoryDescription":"PoloShirts",
"CategoryImage":"******.**.**/web/images/category_poloshirt.jpg"
},

{
"ItemCode":"1160-20-NV-FER03EM1-FER",
"Description":"Wren Ladies Poloshirt",
"TechnicalInfo":"",
"ImageName":"1160NAR.jpeg",
"FfProductCode":"1160-20-NV-EM1-FER",
"CategoryDescription":"Polo Shirts",
"CategoryImage":"https://******.**.**/web/images/category_poloshirt.jpg"
}

]
```

**I want to achieve something like below**

```
<script>
      $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'https://*****************/DirectDownload/GetShopProducts?token=*********&searchString=polo',
    success: function(products){

     for each { 

     <div>
     <h2>Item Code:</h2><p>$ItemCode</p>
     <h2>Item Code:</h2><p>$description</p>
     ....
     </div>

     }

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
success: function(data){
      var html = '<div>';
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            html += '<h2>Item Code:</h2><p>' + value.ItemCode + '</p>';
        });
        html += '</div>';
        $('#result').html(html); //here you set the html variable with the collected data into your desire html tag.
},
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Comment: I adjusted to +1, I did not mean for minus ( - ), your solution brings uncaught typeError ...

Comment: Works fine for me, https://jsfiddle.net/8hf0Lwgy/ debug your code, check your data variable.

Comment: Hi, you have var data = [ ] in your example (at top), where do /can I add this part? @Ektorr

Comment: It is as simple as adding e.g. var data2 = data; , then changing the 'data' in the $.each to 'data2'

Comment: I put the data that you posted in the question. These data is retreived in the ajax call, here: "success: function(data){" console log your "data" in the success and verify it

Comment: ill come back to you in 10 mins or so, will play around with console

Comment: Yeah, same response uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

See above (edited post) how my script looks

Comment: when I do "data" it says data is not defined .... but if I change the success: to ...   success: function(e){console.log(e)}, it of course shows the data in the console

Comment: That is weird. Try with "e" and pass it in the each If It works.

Comment: Still getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"ItemCode":"1100-M-NV-FER03EM2-FER","Description":"Osprey Deluxe .... and if it ry to do just check in console 'data' ... Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: It's possible that your "e" is a string, parse it to json like $.each(JSON.parse(e), function (index, value) {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248699/discussion-between-richag-and-ektorr).

Comment: perfect :) all working